# Spring Boot JPA: Mapping an Entity field with Map<Entity, Integer> causes 'Unsupported Media Type' error

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

Working on a Spring Boot application where I have an Drone entity with a field "medications" that I'm trying to map as a Map<Medication, Integer>. The goal is to associate medications carried by the drone with their corresponding quantity. However, when I try to create or update a drone with this mapping using JSON in the request body, I consistently encounter an 'Unsupported Media Type' error:

```
2023-08-30T20:49:24.538+03:00  WARN 12444 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' is not supported]
```

Previously I used a List for the medications field and it all worked well. Also posting a DroneDto without the Map<Medication,Integer> medications field works.
This is how I mapped medications in the Drone entity:

```
@ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "drones_medications_map",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="drone_id")})
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "medication_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @Column(name = "count")
    private Map<Medication, Integer> medications;
```

For the post request I pass a DroneDto:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class DroneDto {
    private int id;
    private String serialNumber;
    private DroneModel droneModel;
    private int weightLimit;
    private int batteryCapacity;
    private DroneState droneState;
    private Map<Medication, Integer> medications = new HashMap<>();
    private User user;
}
```

DroneController snippet:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class DroneController {
    @Autowired
    private DroneService droneService;

    @PostMapping("/user/{userId}/drones/create")
    public ResponseEntity<DroneDto> saveDrone(@PathVariable("userId") int userId, @RequestBody DroneDto droneDto){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(droneService.saveDrone(droneDto, userId));
    }
```

For the controller I tried
`@PostMaping(value = "/user/{userId}/drones/create" consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)` 
but it's still the same.